# Transform JSON array to JSON object in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Using Azure Logic Apps, i'm trying to transform JSON array to JSON object.
For example, if i have an array as:

```
[
  {
    name: 'john'
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'sarah'
    id: '2'
  },
]
```

I'm would like to have as output:

```
{
'1': 'john',
'2': 'sarah'
}
```

Comment: Try using "Parse JSON" connector to parse your JSON array - [
  {
    name: 'john'
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'sarah'
    id: '2'
  },
]. Initialize empty ([]) and "Array" type variable named "x". Then use "For Each" connector on the generated "Parse JSON output". Inside foreach, use "Append to array variable" on "x" to add your custom output - {'1': 'john', '2': 'sarah'}. Let me know, if this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First init Json Result:

[image]

Then in foreach loop (TestArray is our array with data) add compose with Expression `"addProperty(variables('JsonResult'),item()?['id'],item()?['name'])"` and set variable with output from compose:

[image]

In the foreach settings be sure to enable *concurrency control*, and set the *Degree of Parallelism* to *1*. This is to ensure a sequential run and the variable not being written over in between.

Example run:
[image]
[image]

Code for LA:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Add_property": {
                        "inputs": "@addProperty(variables('JsonResult'),item()?['id'],item()?['name'])",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Set_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "JsonResult",
                            "value": "@outputs('Add_property')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Add_property": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('TestArray')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Init_Json_Result": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Init_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "TestArray",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "john"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "2",
                                    "name": "sarah"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Init_Json_Result": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "JsonResult",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Init_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Test_result": {
                "inputs": "@variables('JsonResult')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Great that's what i need

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments above, posting this as an answer. You can follow below steps to achieve this:

1. Just for testing the flow, add Initialize variable action:
   [image]
2. Parse the input Array:
   [image]
3. Then, Initialize empty array variable:
   [image]
4. Then, use For Each control and inside it you can use Append to array variable action:
   [image]

*Now, you are good to use `output` variable, which has your resultant array.*

**Tested result:**
[image]

**JSON code for this Logic App:**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "output",
                            "value": {
                                "@{items('For_each')['id']}": "@{items('For_each')['name']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@variables('output')",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://prod-33.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/a656267dd18d46d2aa21e79e4012ba29/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=eBgZCaKgCDWiMWjm7JGNNb1-QyXbnT5AlVgBQt1GF48"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Http"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "output",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "input",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "name": "john"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "2",
                                    "name": "sarah"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('input')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "name",
                                "id"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: the output would an object not an array though

Comment: Output is an array variable and it will be have an array of these custom objects.

Comment: I have updated snippets also which show output variable value.