# Transform D365 F&O data events to manageable json format

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics

I have a service bus getting data events pushed on a regular basis. I've been given the task to transform the data to a more manageable format using Azure Logic Apps.
I've simplified the data received from the data event.

The data I'm given is in this format, but can vary in number of fields and fieldnames:

```
{
    "body": {
        "InputParameters": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "Attributes": [
                        {
                            "key": "first_name",
                            "value": "john"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "last_name",
                            "value": "doe"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "age",
                            "value": {
                                "Value": 25
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want to end up with this output:

```
{
    "first_name": "john",
    "last_name": "doe",
    "age": 25
}
```

I've tried using "Select" like this with `concat(item()?['key'], ': ', item()?['value'])`

[image]

which generates this output:

```
[
    "first_name: john",
    "last_name: doe",
    "age: 25"
]
```

That is not far from the desired result, but not quite there.

I've also tried a solution much like the one mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526212/transform-json-array-to-json-object-in-azure-logic-apps), but my dataset consists of at least 400 lines, so it ends up taking more than a minute.

I'm at a loss. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What kind of output you want?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin its listed in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also tried a solution much like the one mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526212/transform-json-array-to-json-object-in-azure-logic-apps) but my dataset consists of at least 400 lines, so it ends up taking more than a minute.

AFAIK, a significant amount of time is needed to perform a set of operations on 400 lines irrespective of any action you choose in logic app. You can either use Foreach loop as per this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526212/transform-json-array-to-json-object-in-azure-logic-apps) or below approach.

***Workflow***-

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

***Select*** :-

```
From: first(body('Parse_JSON')?['InputParameters'])?['value']?['Attributes']
Map: addProperty(variables('result'),item()?['key'],item()?['value'])
```

***Compose*** :-

```
Compose: string(body('Select'))
Compose 2: replace(replace(replace(outputs('Compose'), '[{', '{'), '}]', '}'), '},{', ',')
```

***Code***-

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Add_Property_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initial_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@string(body('Select'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Select": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@replace(replace(replace(outputs('Compose'), '[{', '{'), '}]', '}'), '},{', ',')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initial_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Data",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "{\n        \"InputParameters\": [\n            {\n                \"value\": {\n                    \"Attributes\": [\n                        {\n                            \"key\": \"first_name\",\n                            \"value\": \"john\"\n                        },\n                        {\n                            \"key\": \"last_name\",\n                            \"value\": \"doe\"\n                        },\n                        {\n                            \"key\": \"age\",\n                            \"value\": \"25\"\n                        }\n                    ]\n                }\n            }\n        ]\n    }"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('Data')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "InputParameters": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "Attributes": {
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "key": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "required": [
                                                            "key",
                                                            "value"
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "array"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "value"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Add_Property_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Select": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@first(body('Parse_JSON')?['InputParameters'])?['value']?['Attributes']",
                    "select": "@addProperty(variables('result'),item()?['key'],item()?['value'])"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Select"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "InputParameters": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "Attributes": {
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "key": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        "required": [
                                                            "key",
                                                            "value"
                                                        ],
                                                        "type": "object"
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "array"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "value"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

***Output***-

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This gets me really close to my desired input apart from the "age" property having an "inner value" that i also wanted extracted. But that's the least of my concerns right now. Marking this as the solution